# Mark location of all companies on map

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I want to mark the location(longitude and latitude) of all companies listed as posts in wordpress on a map just like http://finntakst.no/ have done it. 
I have been trying it since 5 hours

Comment: We're here to help you but first attempt has to be given by you. I would appreciate if you could share what code have you written or tried so far.

Comment: I haven't written any code yet but i have tried to do some research on it. I have found plugins that would allow to show multiple markers on the map. But I am unable to understand how to get longitude and latitude from all the posts dynamically to add up in the map.

Comment: I have added custom fields for longitude and latitude in the posts

Comment: If you have custom fields then you can make it dynamic easily. Plugins can work but you have to try.

Comment: @FaizanZahid connect me and lets do it together :D

Comment: I will get to you in a while . and thanks for corporation

Answer (score 1):

You can use plugin to achieve it

Try intergeo map plugin, here is a link to download it https://wordpress.org/plugins/intergeo-maps/

Simply activate the plugin and you can do it easily

Comment: my question still remains there. How to get the longitude and latitude from the custom post fields I have created

Comment: You can customize it with width and height

Comment: it's mot about the size of map its about marking the longitude and latitude(which are present as CPF) on the map dynamically

Comment: If you want to select multiple point in map, then you can use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-location-google-map/